# How to convert Spark RDD to pandas dataframe in ipython?

Tags: python, pandas, ipython, pyspark, rdd

I have a `RDD` and I want to convert it to `pandas` `dataframe`. I know that to convert and `RDD` to a normal `dataframe` we can do

```
df = rdd1.toDF()
```

But I want to convert the `RDD` to `pandas` `dataframe` and not a normal `dataframe`. How can I do it?

Answer (score 47):

You can use function [`toPandas()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html):

> Returns the contents of this DataFrame as Pandas pandas.DataFrame.
>
> This is only available if Pandas is installed and available.

```
>>> df.toPandas()  
   age   name
0    2  Alice
1    5    Bob
```

Comment: What is the difference between toDF() and toPandas()?

Comment: @jezrael, how to convert only first 10 rows of `spark df to pandas df`?

Answer (score 17):

You'll have to use a Spark DataFrame as an intermediary step between your RDD and the desired Pandas DataFrame.

For example, let's say I have a text file, `flights.csv`, that has been read in to an RDD:

```
flights = sc.textFile('flights.csv')
```

You can check the type:

```
type(flights)
<class 'pyspark.rdd.RDD'>
```

If you just use `toPandas()` on the RDD, it won't work.  Depending on the format of the objects in your RDD, some processing may be necessary to go to a Spark DataFrame first.  In the case of this example, this code does the job:

```
# RDD to Spark DataFrame
sparkDF = flights.map(lambda x: str(x)).map(lambda w: w.split(',')).toDF()

#Spark DataFrame to Pandas DataFrame
pdsDF = sparkDF.toPandas()
```

You can check the type:

```
type(pdsDF)
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

Comment: I think `pdsDF = sparkDF.toPandas` is missing the () to actually call the method. It should be: `pdsDF = sparkDF.toPandas()`

Comment: What is the difference between toDF() and toPandas()?

Comment: toDF() converts an RDD to a Spark DataFrame, and toPandas() converts a Spark DataFrame to a Pandas DataFrame.  The two kinds of DataFrames are different types.