# Python Read from SQL to pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am using the below script to read data from `MSSQL` Server to `Pyspark` dataframes.

```
DFFSA = spark.read.format("jdbc").option("url", jdbcURLDev).option("driver", MSSQLDriver ).option("dbtable", "FSA.dbo.FSA").option("user", "DevUser").option("password", "password").load();
```

This generates a Pyspark dataframe. How can I do so with pandas dataframe? I know I can convert the resulting dataframe into a pandas dataframe using the `toPandas()` function but this is taking a lot of time since I am reading millions of rows.

Comment: your pandas read into dataframe might not be faster. What is the size of the data you are looking at?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ this is actually not a dupe of that question. He's asking how to convert a pyspark dataframe to pandas, which can be done using the `toPandas()` method. A better dupe candidate would be: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34817549/how-to-convert-spark-rdd-to-pandas-dataframe-in-ipython

Comment: @pault Thanks a bunch, edited the duplicates list.

Comment: `toPandas()` will be slow for millions of rows. There's no way around it because all of your data has to be serialized through the head node. A better question is why do you need it in pandas? You should think about how to do your processing in spark instead.