# convert dataframe to list of rows pyspark glue

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark, aws-glue

How can I convert my dataframe `df` to a list of rows?

**Code**

```py
df = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame_from_options(
    connection_type = "s3",
    connection_options = {"paths": ["s3://data/tmp1/file.csv"]},
    format = "csv",
)
df = df.toDF()
list = df.values.tolist()
```

**Error**

```
dataframe has no attribute values
```

Comment: Did you try `toPandas()`?

Comment: how please. @E.Zeytinci

Comment: do you mean **df = df.toPandas()** and then **liste = df.values.tolist()** ?

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/34817549/11301900 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO, you can use [`toPandas()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.3.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.toPandas),

```py
df = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame_from_options(
    connection_type="s3", 
    connection_options={"paths": ["s3://data/tmp1/file.csv"]}, 
    format="csv")

df = df.toPandas()
liste = df.values.tolist()
```

Answer (score 0):

In glue, you may use DyanamicFrame.map() method (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-extensions-dynamic-frame.html#aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-extensions-dynamic-frame-map)

```
df.map(to_list)
def to_list(rec):
       rec["list"] = [rec["col1"], rec["col2"] ]
       del rec["col1"]
       del rec["col2"]
```